# Xamarin.Forms MVVM Light IDialogService ShowMessage throwing native exception

Tags: c#, mvvm, xamarin, xamarin.forms, mvvm-light

i recently started working with MVVM Light and just used the IDialogService for the first time.

My ViewModelLocator

```
ServiceLocator.SetLocatorProvider(() => SimpleIoc.Default);

// Register the dialog service provided by mvvm light
SimpleIoc.Default.Register<IDialogService, DialogService>();
```

My ViewModel

```
private IRestService _restService;

public OrderViewModel (IDialogService dialogService )
{ 
   _dialogService = dialogService;
}
```

And finally using ShowMessage:

```
await _dialogService.ShowMessage("test", "test", "Ok", "Nop", (result) => { 
   if (result)
   {
      //...
   }
   else
   {
      //...
   }
});
```

Which is causing this exception:

```
Java.Lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 
'android.content.res.Resources$Theme android.content.Context.getTheme()'
on a null object reference
```

Can someone tell me whats going on ?

Comment: Does your activity inherit from mvvm light's `ActivityBase`?

Comment: Please see my answer

Comment: Do you have debug "Just My Code" enabled?  https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/17418.the-famous-system-servicemodel-faultexception1-was-unhandled-by-user-code.aspx

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem is, that current activity has not been set. The problem is, that MvvmLight needs `CurrentActivity` to be of type `ActivityBase`. So i think the `DialogService` not really compatible with Forms, because Forms requires the Activity to inherit from `FormsAppCompatActivity`. That would make up a nice diamond shaped inheritance, which is not possible, because C# doesn't support multiple inheritance.

So you could use ACR User Daialogs: https://www.nuget.org/packages/Acr.UserDialogs/

See https://github.com/aritchie/userdialogs#android-initialization-in-your-main-activity for the Setup.

And you can register it

```
SimpleIoc.Default.Register<IUserDialogs>(UserDialogs.Instance);
```

Comment: Okay i used acr userdialogs bevore, i just thought that i could use the already implemented user dialogs from mvvm light.