# Implementing acr.UserDialogs in Xamarin.Forms with mvvmlight

Tags: c#, mvvm, xamarin.forms, mvvm-light

For school we are developing a mobile app with Xamarin Forms.
We use mvvmlight in the project.

Now I was looking around for how to show dialogs, alerts etc. and stumbled upon [acr.UserDialogs](https://github.com/aritchie/userdialogs) which has everything we need.

I added 
`UserDialogs.Init(this);` to my MainActivity.cs

And when I try to register it in my ViewModelLocator:

`SimpleIoc.Default.Register<IUserDialogs, UserDialogs>();`

This doesn't work because UserDialogs is Static type.

I found a similiar question [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37051820/xamarin-forms-mvvm-light-idialogservice-showmessage-throwing-native-exception)
Which gives the following suggestion

`SimpleIoc.Default.Register<IUserDialogs>(UserDialogs.Instance);`

But this doesn't work neither.

Anyone got any other suggestions?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try this way. I just tested in my environment and it works fine for me.

Put this in your MainActivity

```
Acr.UserDialogs.UserDialogs.Init(this);
```

And Bind your dialog with command in your viewmodel

```
private RelayCommand _yourCommand;

public RelayCommand YourCommand{
   get{
       return _yourCommand
          ?? (_yourCommand = new RelayCommand( async () => {
              UserDialogs.Instance.ShowLoading("TEST");
          }
   }
}
```

I do not register arc.UserDialog in my ViewModelLocator but register 'IDialogService'

```
public ViewModelLocator()
{
   ...
   SimpleIoc.Default.Register<IDialogService, DialogService>();
   ...
}
```

And My ViewModel

```
public class MyViewModel : ViewModelBase
{
   ...
   private IDialogService _dialogService;
   ...
   //ViewModel Constructor
   public SignUpViewModel(INavigationService navigationService, IDialogService dialogService){
       _dialogService = dialogService;
   }
}
```